# How to create a function which takes value from list and put into method and collecting the results?

Tags: python, function

I'm building a regression model and I want to plot predictions on a graph,
So first I need to collect this predictions.

I can get them using `lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform([[len(cases)+i]]))`, when `i` must be 1, 2, 3, ... etc.

I created a list named `i` which is range of number 1-30.

And now I need to create a function which will get each item from `i`, paste them into method, get the results and store them to list.

Definitely don't know how to create this function. Seems to be easy, but I even don't know where I can learn about creating functions in a right way.

Comment: Have you tried `for` loops? https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 0):

Well this was easier than I thought:

```
predictions =np.array([[]])
n = np.array([i for i in range(1, 30)]).astype(float)
b = len(cases) + n
b  = b.reshape(b.shape[0], -1)
for n in lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(b)):
    predictions = lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(b))
```